# Sublime Text 3 - Jupyter interaction via Hermes

Tags: python, sublimetext3, jupyter

Using Sublime Text 3 for quite some time for Python I found [Hermes](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Hermes) to let ST3 interact with Jupyter. The installation via Package Control worked but now I have problems to connect to a kernel. Searching the web for some time I found so far only little help on the setup of Hermes and almost nothing on its usage.

I am using an Anaconda installation (Python 3) only for me (i.e. into /Users/the_user/anaconda3) on macOS 10.13.6. The documentation of Hermes states that Jupyter might not find a kernel installed via Conda. So I entered the path (/Users/the_user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels) to the Jupyter kernel into the user configuration file of Hermes. Furthermore, I made the path know to the system.

Now, using the "basic way" to connect to start a kernel via `Hermes: connect kernel` and then `New kernel` nothing was shown.

- Was I supposed to see a list of available kernels?

Reading the error message I entered the path to the json file in kernels/python3/ Somehow, a connection was established but the options mention in the section **Execution** of the Hermes documentation were not available.

Seems like I am missing something.

- So, how do I have to configure Hermes?
- Are there a little more elaborate documentations out there on the setup and usage of Hermes?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I found a solution that at least solved my problem.

Since there is a similar package called [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) for the editor Atom, as mentioned on the website for Hermes I looked into that and finally found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376638/no-kernel-for-language-json-found-hydrogen-on-atom#).

As described there the command issued in my case in the Terminal

> python -m ipykernel install --user

solves my problem.

So I answer myself and hope it helps others, too.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your effort. So for someone who has not yet tried it, it seems hard to go through your question, understand the problems, without actually having them, and only then the answer should make sense. Maybe you could update the answer and transform it into some kind of recipe, leaving out the problems :) 1. what you installed in what way, 2. what you changed, and 3. how to start the whole thing. In which terminal did you issue the command?  Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look into it again. In fact I switched to Atom for Python because the Hydrogen package for Atom worked out of the box. Hence, I didn't use the Hermes package for quite some.